# Why might lower settings of a dashboard fan not work if the highest does?

Tags: nissan, hvac, heater-blower

My wife bought a Nissan Note second hand and the internal ventilation fan works on the highest setting (3 or 4) but not on the lower settings. We've checked the fuses and all seems fine there. Could it be a problem with the switches inside/behind the knob?

Bonus points if you can also tell me how to fix this. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great post, it really helped me solve the same problem.
I took some photos specific to the Nissan Note, I can send them if you want to expand the article.
My problem turned out to be a failed solder joint on the resistor board.
Firstly remove the glove box by taking out 5 screws (2 underneath and 3 on top) BLUE circles...
[image: bottom screw location]
[image: Top screw locations]
remove the glove box and look for the wires connected to the heater control module RED arrow
[image: heater control module in situ]
remove 2xTorx head screws holding the module in place
Remove the connector block.
Repair or change the module -mine had a failed solder joint!
[image: Broken solder joint]//i.stack.imgur.com/eJSWX.jpg

Comment: Yes *PLEASE* to the photos. If you could add them here like the one above that would be great. I'm not sure how to remove the thing to work on it so that would be nice to see as well if you could post it. :)

Comment: Answer updated. I read about one poor who chap took out the car's entire dashboard and the steering column... http://www.noteownersclub.co.uk/forum/blower-removal-hell_topic1766.html

Comment: That's the **EXACT** same unit and problem I had. Photos: http://goo.gl/WR8Kx4 and http://goo.gl/02uZho

Comment: Nice one. So, Nissan need to "discuss" quality control with one of their suppliers!

Answer (score 12):

The first thing I would check is the blower motor resistor. This device will usually be located near the blower motor under the dash, and will have an electrical connector with 4 to 5 wires coming out of it. It's job is to add more resistance to current flow with each lower speed. It really just 3 resisters wired in series all inside one component.

- High (4), usually a seperate circuit that by passes the resistor and has a relay for higher current flow required  in the high setting
- Med-High (3), goes through resistor one slightly limiting current flow
- Med-Low (2), goes through resistor one and two limiting current flow a little further
- Low (1), goes through resistors one two and three limiting current flow the most

The most common cause of two or more speeds not working is the resistor, because if resistor two burns out it will affect speeds 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4.

Here is a typical wiring Diagram, this one does not use a separate circuit and relay for high.

[image: Wiring Diagram]

The green tracing is low, and goes through all three resistors
The blue tracing is med low, and goes through resistor 2 and 3
The red tracing is med high, and goes through resistor 3 only.

If Resistor two is blow it will prevent green and blue circuits from working. The arrow with the [free hand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775) around it points too resistor two.

Here are some examples of a typical blower motor resistor

[image: Blower motor resistor]
[image: Blower motor resistor 2]

Here is a typical location

[image: Typical Location]

If you decide to do this yourself take pictures along the way and I will update my answer making a tutorial with your pictures. I don't have access to a Nissan Note stateside.

Note there is a small possibility that it's a different problem and there are some additional trouble shooting steps you can take to confirm.