# How to troubleshoot a fan that won't work unless it's on it's on the highest setting?

Tags: electrical, ac, hvac, vauxhall, fan

My car fan won't work unless it's on 4 (full power). I have 4 options of power for the fan 1 - 4 but nothing happens on options 1 - 3.

I have taken the panel off and cleaned all the contacts for the fan control (with a bit of very fine sand paper) but it didn't seem to help.

I also checked all the fuses related to fans and it all seems Ok (although I wouldn't expect it to work at all if a fuse had blown).

Car: Vauxhall Vectra 04 Reg 1.8

I have seen this post: [Why might lower settings of a dashboard fan not work if the highest does?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/495/why-might-lower-settings-of-a-dashboard-fan-not-work-if-the-highest-does) which seems to say the resistor has blown so does anyone have any information on where to find the `blower motor resistor` on my vectra? (I am keen on fixing this myself if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a bit more research and it looks like this link sorts my issue:

http://www.blower-motor-resistor.co.uk/vauxhall-vectra-c-blower-motor-resistor.html

Comment: If your vehicle is equipped with air bags, I always disconnect the battery while working under the dash.