# Vauxhall Vectra C Blower Motor Sqealing / Clunking

Tags: electrical, hvac, vauxhall, fan

I have just replaced my Blower Motor Resistor as my fan wouldn't work on any setting other than 4 (in line with a previous post: [How to troubleshoot a fan that won't work unless it's on it's on the highest setting?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-troubleshoot-a-fan-that-wont-work-unless-its-on-its-on-the-highest-set/5503#5503)). When on 4 I noticed a slight squeal but now that it's working on 1, 2 and 3 I notice a big squeal / clunking when the fan is on the lower settings.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or do I need to replace the blower motor?

Car: Vauxhall Vextra C - 2004

Answer (score 3):

Sounds very much like a worn blower motor so you at least have to get at the motor to find out what is worn. While you're that deep in the car you might as well replace it with a new one.